# Is this program for binary to decimal is correct?

Tags: c, binary, numbers, decimal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main() {
    long long int bin;
    int dec=0,i;

    scanf("%lld", &bin);
    for(i=0; bin!=0; i++){
        if(bin%10==0 || bin%10==1){
            dec+=(bin%10)*pow(2,i);
            bin/=10;
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid Binary number!!\n");
            return 0;
        }

    }
    printf("%d\n", dec);


    return 0;
}
```

I make this program to convert binary to decimal.
There are many code in online but I want to know
Is everything ok with this code?

Comment: When you tried it, did it give you the correct result? Isn't that the main test to do?

Comment: @AntonH Probably some believe that if the code is containing undefined behavior, it can actually give them nasal demons..

Comment: @EugeneSh. The only UB I see happens when the `scanf()` fails.

Comment: @EOF I am just explaining the possible reason to ask for a review *before* actually trying it :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah, that's a fair point. I always get terrible congestion of my sinuses after nasal demon infections.

Comment: Calculation can only be done up to 20 bits.(When `long long` is 64 bits)

Comment: The use of `pow` is bad. The whole thing is bad. Input to a string, and examine each `char`.

Comment: Note: Code could use `scanf("%llo", &bin);
    for(i=0; bin!=0; i++){
        if(bin%8==0 || bin%8==1){ ...` and handle up to 21 or so binary digits.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Another possible UB is signed integer overflow with `dec+=(bin%10)*pow(2,i);`

Comment: While this is probably an exercise, C provides `strtol` which using `base = 2` will provide the conversion for you.

Comment: 'I make this program' - you WROTE this program.  That's 5% of the work.  The other 95% is testing and debugging.  You need to do that too.

Comment: @AntonH Due to the presense of undefined behaviour in C, misguided "try it and see" advice can be dangerous, allowing students to miss errors that cause non-portable and subtle yet confusing and difficult to debug issues later on. Please avoid that kind of advice in the future.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I assume you wrote that comment because you had the intention to be insightful; any other assumption seems disrespectful. Writing comments is <5% of being insightful. The other >95% is learning how to be insightful. See also, my previous addressed to AntonH who had a similar view to you.

Comment: Insight?  No, it's just the way things are in engineering. You would not throw together an airliner, fill it up with pax and send it off without a commissioning phase, so it is with software.  If you have not tested and debugged it, you have not performed the necessary steps to ensure its operation to spec.  You wrote it, you define its operation, you write its test spec and you test and debug it.  If you have a specific issue, please ask here, but don't expect to outsource complete testing to SO :((

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to read character by character and convert directly to a machine number. That more clearly expresses your intent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long n = 0;
    int c;
    fputs("enter a number in base 2: ", stdout);
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (n >= (ULLONG_MAX >> 1) + 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "binary number is too large\n");
            return 1;
        }
        n <<= 1;
        if (c == '0')
            n += 0;
        else if (c == '1')
            n += 1;
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "bad binary digit '%c'\n", c);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("that number in base 10 is %llu\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Completely untested.  Negative numbers left as an exercise (caution: shifting into the sign bit of a signed integer provokes undefined behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Your code does have some issues:

1. You should always check for `scanf` failing. On success, `scanf` returns the number of items in the argument list successfully filled, so if the return value is something other than 1 (in your case) you should print an error and stop there.
2. You don't need to use `pow` at all. Multiplying an integer by a power of 2 is the same as shifting it left, but faster since you aren't calling a function that returns a `double`.  Replace `*pow(2, i)` with `<< i` and you get the same result.
3. From a usability perspective, you should print out messages to the screen.

This is much better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main() 
{
    long long int bin;
    int dec=0,i;
    printf("Enter a number in base 2: ");
    if(scanf("%lld", &bin)!=1)
    {
        printf("Error reading your input.");
        return -1;
    }
    for(i=0; bin!=0; i++)
    {
        if(bin%10==0 || bin%10==1)
        {
            dec+=(bin%10) << i;
            bin/=10;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid Binary number!!\n");
            return 0;
        }

    }
    printf("That number in base 10 is: %d\n", dec);


    return 0;
}
```